# Restrict web app to one tab and one browser at one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, web-applications

I have to restrict my app to one tab and one browser at one time. I am doing it through Javascript and cookies. Basically I am checking when a user hits my site after login if cookies are set or not. If they are then redirect to logout, otherwise set new cookies.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    if(!$.cookie('number')) {
        $.cookie('number', 1); 
    } else {
        $.removeCookie('number');
        window.location = "{{ url('/logout') }}";
    }
});
```

When the user tries to open the web site in a new tab as a cookie is already set from the first tab then it will redirect to logout:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
    $.removeCookie('number');
});
```

When user comes back to the first tab due to the `focus()` event it will check if a cookie is set or not. If not then it will redirect to logout

```
$(window).focus(function() {
    if (!$.cookie('number')) {
        //$.removeCookie('number');
        window.location = "{{ url('/logout') }}";
    }
});
```

My problem is that when I open a new site on my active tab, lets say I opened my web app first time then I open any other web site by typing a URL, when I come back to my site it is still showing my app although it should redirect to logout.

Comment: Where is the php part?

Comment: cookies are not crosesite

Comment: this implementation will only save you from multiple windows from your site opened form the same browser

Comment: i have also implement logic for different browser as i store status in db ... but my problem is " I opened my web app first time then I open any other web site by typing a URL, when I come back to my site it is still showing my app although it should redirect to logout."